# The version compatibility relationship of Xorg-server, Mesa(OpenGL) and Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, xorg, mesa

I found lots of documents to explain the software relation(stack) of Xserver, Mesa and Linux kernel like as following.

[1] https://blogs.igalia.com/itoral/2014/07/29/a-brief-introduction-to-the-linux-graphics-stack/
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure
..etc

But I can't find the documents to explain which version of Xserver should use which version of Mesa and Linux Kernel and they are all hardware dependency.

Only Intel's [website](https://01.org/node/18011) has information of the recipe with its own.

I wonder do they have compatibility issue of those(Xserver, Mesa and Kernel)?

ex: Is it safe with the newer version Xserver runs on the older version Linux kernel(and vice versa)?